# Time complexity of linear iteration bounded by logarithmic iteration?

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity

I was wondering about the time complexity of something like the following loop (where `work()` is `O(1)`):

```
for (i = 0 to N; i = i * 2) do
    for(j = 0 to i; j = j + 1) do
        work()
    end
end
```

The outer loop takes $\lg(N)$ steps, and the inner loop takes (on the final iteration) $N$ steps. So, a simple bound would be $O(N\lg(N))$. However, the inner loop doesn't fully reach $N$ until the last iteration, so I was wondering if the bound could be narrowed any further.

Answer (score 1):

Derp, nevermind. I observed that on the last iteration, the inner loop takes $N$ steps. On the previous iteration, the inner loop would take $\frac{N}{2}$ steps. Overall, this would take $N, \frac{N}{2}, \frac{N}{4}, \frac{N}{8},...$ steps, which has a geometric sum to $2N$ steps. Therefore, the loop is $O(N)$.